# How to delete a node from a tree. I am trying to delete the node from the function but still it is getting print even after deleting

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am deleting the node from delete function and when print it within function it shows its None

But when done out of the function it prints the value
please correct me, tell me what's wrong in this code

Note:Class Node has only **init** method and other function are outside the class

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None 

def printit(obj):

    if obj:
        printit(obj.left)
        print(obj.data)
        printit(obj.right)
    return

def insert(obj, data):

    if obj.left == None:
        obj.left = Node(data)
        return
    
    if obj.right == None:
        obj.right = Node(data)
        return
    
    insert(obj.left, data)
    

def delet(obj):

    if obj.left == None:
        obj= None
        return
    delet(obj.left)
```

```
f = Node(50)

f.left = Node(15)

f.right = Node(75)

delet(f)

printit(f)
```

Comment: What do you expect `delet` to do? What if `obj.right` is not `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj= None` only affects the value of that *name*. It doesn't affect anything related to the previous value of `obj`.

If you want to change the tree structure, you'll have to assign to an *attribute*, not to a variable name.

Think also what happens when the very *last* node is deleted: then the main program should get its `f` set to `None`. This can only happen if you *return* something that the caller can assign back to their own variable.

For instance:

```
def delet(obj):
    if obj.right is not None:
        obj.right = delet(obj.right)
    elif obj.left is not None:
        obj.left = delet(obj.left)
    else:
        return None
    return obj
```

You should then also use the returned value in the main code:

```
f = Node(50)
f.left = Node(15)
f.right = Node(75)
printit(f)
print("---")

f = delet(f)
printit(f)
print("---")

f = delet(f)
printit(f)
print("---")

f = delet(f)
printit(f)
print("---")
```

Comment: I got this, but same thing when I am doing with insert it is working. Why? So even when inserting new value it should have added the value but outside the function it should not print the new tree, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. When you call `insert` it impacts the tree because `insert` makes an assignment to an attribute of a node. If ever you wanted to pass `None` as first argument to `insert`, to create a *first* node of the tree, then you would need to *return* the new root, and apply the same principle as I have done in `delet`. Both otherwise it is not needed.

Comment: Yes, I got it now, thankyou soo much :)